Gensim Doc2VecKeyedVectors call to similar_by_vector() results in "too many values to unpack"
I'm using Gensim 4.0 to store vectors in Doc2VecKeyedVectors to perform similarity lookups, but I'm getting an error.
Here is some sample code:
model = <load a Doc2Vec model>
corpus = <load an object which returns key/words pairs>

kv = Doc2VecKeyedVectors(vector_size=50)
for key, words in corpus:
    vector = model.infer_vector(words)
    kv.add_vector(key, vector)

test_words = ['word1', 'word2', ...]
vector = model.infer_vector(test_words)
sims = kv.similar_by_vector(vector, topn=200)

The call to similar_by_vector() throws a "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" on line 758 of keyedvectors.py in most_similar() method.
I walked through the source code, and it looks like it's expecting the key to be passed in with the vector, which seems odd based on the method signature.
Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

I figured out the problem.  The code sample I gave left out the fact that the call to infer_vector() was actually a call to a remote server, which was returning a list of floats, not an ndarray.  Well, I never converted it back to an ndarray before calling similar_by_vector(), and that was the cause of the problem.

That's odd, because Gensim's .infer_vector() has no built-in ability to call a remote server. If that was happening, some other very significant and non-standard thing was happening in your code, unshown, at that line or earlier. But glad you worked it out!

Separately: note that in recent Gensim versions, Doc2VecKeyedVectors is just an alias to KeyedVectors - it's just a generic key-to-vector store, without specialization as to where the vectors came from.

The infer_vector() call I showed was a shortcut in my code example.  I'm running a model on a separate server and I exposed an "infer_vector" function on it.  Because ndarrays can't be JSON serialized, I had to convert them to lists of floats before sending them.  I didn't convert them back to ndarrays on the receiving side, which caused the issue.

Got it. I was mainly just aiming to make the point: if necessary code details weren't in the question – or further, the question made it look like the line-of-code that's erroring is some standard function from a shared library, when it's actualy customized it to do something different – there's no chance others would have been able to help.

Yup, understood.  That line of code was the key issue, and I should have spelled it out better.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
